# C# передача делегата в качестве параметра метода

Tags: c#, делегаты, передача-параметров

```
public delegate int Method(T obj);

public int AnyMethod(Method CompareTo)
{
       T obj1, obj2;

       //...
       return obj1.CompareTo(obj2)
}
```

> Ошибка    CS1061  "T" не содержит определения "CompareTo", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "CompareTo", принимающий тип "T" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Как правильно передать делегат в таком случае?

Comment: @AlexKrass, в сообщении об ошибке опечатки нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy ок, увидел опечатку в коде, в текст ошибки уже не вчитывался.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public delegate int Method<T>(T obj) where T : IComparable;
```